# Jquery tab in exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I am using exposed filter in my views for taxonomy term. It is displaying taxonomy terms in 'drop down list'. Is it possible to use jquery tab or button instead? Please let me know if there is any way to do so via template or any module.

Thank you.